# Title xaxis in custom function using R plot_ly

Tags: r, function, plotly, axis-labels

I'm learning R. With the help of [Maximilian Peters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349798/7004018), I wrote a custom function to make a bunch of plotly scatterplots. I want to label the x and y axis titles with the column names from those variables.

Here is the code:

```
library(plotly)
my_plot <- function(x, y, ...) {
  plot_ly(y = y, x = x, ...) %>%
    add_markers() %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title = deparse(substitute(x))), 
           yaxis = list(title = deparse(substitute(y))))
}
my_plot(y = mtcars$mpg, x = mtcars$disp)
```

This sets the xaxis title to "x", but I want it to be "disp".

I also tried this code:

```
my_plot <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  plot_ly(y = data[[y]], x = data[[x]], ...) %>%
    add_markers() %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title = deparse(substitute(data[[x]]))), 
           yaxis = list(title = deparse(substitute(data[[y]]))))
}
my_plot(data = mtcars, y = 'mpg', x = 'disp')
```

This sets the xaxis title to "data[[x]]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I posted too quick. The solution was simple.

```
my_plot <- function(data, x, y, ...) {
  plot_ly(y = data[[y]], x = data[[x]], ...) %>%
    add_markers() %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title = x), 
           yaxis = list(title = y))
}
my_plot(data = mtcars, y = 'mpg', x = 'disp')
```